# import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

Tags: android, import, dependencies

I am a newbie to Android programming. 
I want to use android Support Libraries to go witj the class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.
So i added in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
...
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:29.0.0"
```

}

However, in my Java code, i always get an error with

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

It looks like the class is not known. I looked up this problem in many posts, but i could not find a solution to this, since the implementation of support libraries via build gradle usually fixes the problem.

I use Android Studio 3.4.2 and in the SDK tools i added the Support repository:
[SDK-Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCHGo.png)

Since i am a newbie, it could be a very basic mistake e.g. in confuration of the project.

Comment: Did you sync project from gradle?

Comment: Yes, i think so, i add a picture